# I get the error message:Expression: (L “String is not null terminated” & & 0)

Tags: c

When I run my Program，I get the error message.I don't konw how to correct it.May I get a help?

```
char dir[1024]="C:\\Users\\UserName\Desktop\\new folder\\Pauli\\T3";
void check_dir(char *dir)
{
int i;
i = 0;
while (dir[i] != '\0') {
    if (dir[i] == '/')
        dir[i] = '\\';
    i++;
}
strcat_s(dir, sizeof(dir),"\\");
}
```

Comment: Please enable the compiler warnings.

Comment: also, `sizeof(dir)` == `sizeof(char *)`, right?

Comment: When posting question about build errors, please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question. And. more importantly, the actual, complete and unedited error output in the body of the question. Also indicate on which lines in the source you show the errors are. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nitpick: the error is a *runtime* error of `strcat_s()`.

Comment: yes ,I should add "\" before the word "Desktop",but this is not key,I run the program again,have the same question.

Comment: @Jinunmeng see Sourav's comment and my answer explaining it in more detail. `sizeof(dir)` in your code equals the storage size of *a single pointer* -- depending on your platform typically 4 or 8. NOT what you want.

Comment: Thanks all the answerer,this is my first time to ask question on the stack overflow.I'll edit my question in detail next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(dir)` doesn't do what you obviously expect here. As `dir` is a `char *` inside your function, it just gives you the size of the pointer (*). Your only option is to pass the size of the array to your `check_dir()` function, too:

```
void check_dir(char *dir, size_t bufsize)
{
    [...]
    strcat_s(dir, bufsize, "\\");
}
```

(*) In the scope where dir is declared `char dir[1024]`, `sizeof(dir)` *will* give you the expected result.

*edit:* On a side note, `check_dir()` is a misnomer here, as it doesn't check anything but tries to *normalize* the string to be a windows path with backslashes. Call it  e.g. `win32_normalize_path()` or something like that. Something called `check_<foo>()` should return something (e.g. `int`) containing the result of the check.

Comment: Thank you very much,your question is right.I know how to do.